# Update para remover um pedaço de um campo varchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Tenho uma coluna com um campo varchar. Nessa coluna tem um valor assim:

```
http://dominio/img//12.jpg
```

Quero fazer um update que deixe esse campo assim:

```
http://dominio/img/12.jpg
```

Essa // que quero remover sempre começam em uma posição fixa na string.

Como eu faria esse update?

O update é na tabela toda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem simples, na real:

```
UPDATE TABELA
SET COLUNA = REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUNA, '//', '/'), 'http:/', 'http://');
```

[Fiz um Fiddle pra você](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2e291/1).

[Veja mais sobre o `REPLACE` aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186862.aspx).